# How to get just the node text, not the children's text in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Presume the website layout looks like this:

```html
<div id="monday">
  ...
  <div class="dish">
    Potato Soup
    <br>
    <span>With smoked tofu</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

How, using puppeteer, would I be able to grab just the text node's content, not everything inside `.dish`?

I've tried

```js
let selector = await page.waitForSelector("#monday .dish");
let text = await selector.evaluate(el => el.textContent) ?? "";
```

but that returns `"Potato SoupWith smoked tofu"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`textContent` is meant for that. What you can do is select the first `TEXTNODE` like below :

```
let text = await selector.evaluate(el => Array.from(el.childNodes)
                               .find(node=> node.nodeType === 3)?.textContent)
```

`nodeType === 3` means it's a text node. or you can use `nodeName === '#text'`

```js
const elem = document.querySelector("#monday .dish");

const textNode = Array.from(elem.childNodes).find(r=> r.nodeType === 3)?.textContent;

console.log(textNode)
```

```html
<div id="monday">
  <div class="dish">
    Potato Soup
    <br>
    <span>With smoked tofu</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's also `Node.TEXT_NODE` which is a macro for `3`.